# Flutter Dart Function as a Parameter to Another Function

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, boilerplate

I was looking into the documentation and failed to find an answer to my question:

Suppose I have a function the returns a `Future<String>` that I want to imbed in a second function which could take any other function that is of type `Future<String>`, the syntax -if I am not wrong- would be:

```
String functionTwo(Future<User> Function() putFunctionHere) async {
  await code
  return 'some string';
}
```

If I had to guess with regards to Dart syntax, I would say that it would be:

`String functionTwo(Function putFunctionHere){...}`

Which leads me to my question, why do we have to specify `Future<User> Function()` is it the only way?

And why do we have to put the parentheses next to `Function`

Comment: Some part of your question is answered in this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334714/pass-a-typed-function-as-a-parameter-in-dart)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DART: Passing function in a function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550421/dart-passing-function-in-a-function-as-parameter)

Comment: @ArindamGanguly thank, although partially, it still answers some of my questions. Thank you.

Comment: @SanjaySharma I am sorry, but it doesn't, thank you for the input anyways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a typed function as a parameter in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334714/pass-a-typed-function-as-a-parameter-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax are as follow:

```
OutputType Function(ParameterType1 paramater1, ParameterType2 parameter2...) nameOfFunctionForUsageInsideTheMethod
```

So the following can be read we take a function as argument which must return `Future<User>` and takes no arguments.

```
Future<User> Function() putFunctionHere
```

This function can then be referred to as `putFunctionHere` like:

```
final value = await putFunctionHere()
```

Comment: If I do understand correctly, I can avoid specifying the return type of the embedded function if I want, right? But if I do specify ```Future<String>``` I find myself forced to add the parentheses to ```Function```, any idea as to why that happens?

Comment: You should always specify a return value but if you don't care about the return value you can use `void`, The parentheses is important since it is part of the syntax. The syntax `(Function method)` does in fact mean that you can a object as input which implements the interface `Function`. This is something entirely else and is properly not what you want. This class is documented here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Function-class.html